# My script is failing on an if/else statement

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I was using [this bitbucket backup code](https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/atlassian-bitbucket-diy-backup/src/master/). On running `bitbucket.diy-backup.sh`, it exits from shell at an if statement in `common.sh`.

Attached relevant parts of code from both files -

bitbucket.diy-backup.sh -

```
set -e

SCRIPT_DIR=$(dirname "$0")
source "${SCRIPT_DIR}/utils.sh"
source "${SCRIPT_DIR}/common.sh"
```

common.sh -

```
BACKUP_VARS_FILE=${BACKUP_VARS_FILE:-"${SCRIPT_DIR}"/bitbucket.diy-backup.vars.sh}
...
# Just exits here
if [ -f "${BACKUP_VARS_FILE}" ]; then
    source "${BACKUP_VARS_FILE}"
    debug "Using vars file: '${BACKUP_VARS_FILE}'"
else
    error "'${BACKUP_VARS_FILE}' not found"
    bail "You should create it using '${SCRIPT_DIR}/bitbucket.diy-backup.vars.sh.example' as a template"
fi
```

Here is the file structure - all three files are in the same directory. Ideally, it should go through the first if statement, or maybe it goes to else. But running `./bitbucket.diy-backup.sh` just exits at this statement.

[image: File structure in the machine - all three files - bitbucket.vars, common, bitbucket-backup.sh are in the same folder]

Comment: Are you sure that it **was** running `common.sh`?

Comment: Can you try doing an `echo` before and after the `BACKUP_VARS_FILE` statement to see if control reaches there or not? Also, try executing the `BACKUP_VARS_FILE` statement directly on the shell to check its correctness..